# Constrain Aspect Ratio of Single Window MacOS Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Let's say I have an Obj-C Xcode Project for MacOS. I have a one xib containing two windows. One is the primary window at launch. The second window is opened from a button on the primary window. Other than this, just the appdelegate .h and .m. Both windows are in one xib.

I want to constrain the aspect ratio of the second window but not the primary window.

I have found I can use something like this:

```
[_window setAspectRatio:NSMakeSize(16, 9)];
```

Added to the appdelegate.m under applicationDidFinishLaunching seems to constrain the primary window, but not the second.

Any idea how I can allow a second xib window to be resized, but constrained to an aspect ratio of 16:9 - without constraining the primary window, when both windows are in one xib file?

Comment: Where and how is `_window` declared and assigned?

Comment: Would you show code of button which opens second window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app delegate does not have any connection to the "video window", the `window` property is connected to your main window. You can, for example, add another outlet:

[image]

Then you can set the video window's aspect ratio instead of the main window's.

```
[_videoWindow setAspectRatio:NSMakeSize(16, 9)];
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding a second outlet and then setting aspect worked to force an aspect ratio on an opened window.